# Increase bootable USB available memory

Tags: linux, operating-systems, disk-space, bootable-media, ramdisk

I wanted to know if it is possible to use the USB memory to increase the available disk-space for a bootable OS in an USB.

I have a bootable USB which runs Kali Linux. I noticed that the available disk-space I have changes when I move to a different PC with lower or higher RAM.
However my USB that contains the OS has a lot of free space I was wondering if this can be used to increase my available disk space.

I also noticed the available memory I have regardless of the OS is always half of the RAM of the PC is there any way to increase this?

Comment: A live session depends on the RAM indeed. A live session with persistence depends on the space allocated for persistence in the bootable media. You aren't actually running an installed system. But, me wonders, why someone unaware of this - and asking about it - is doing with Kali which is intended only for people with a solid foundation in Linux?...

Comment: Yes, but the persistence option is available only for Ubuntu is there any way to set this up for other distributions. The only other way I can think of is having two partitions one with the live OS and the other I can use as external memory?

Comment: No, the persistence option is available **at least** for Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives. Kali is a Debian derivative.